# Thunderbird: hide menu (file, edit, view, ..) in compose window

Tags: thunderbird, css

How can I hide the main menu (file, edit, view, ..) in compose window in Thunderbird 102 ?

[image]

I really don't use it, and if I ever need it, I can always press <kbd>F10</kbd> to recall it.

Please don't suggest any addons to do this.
Is there a way to do it by modifying `about:config` or `userChrome.css` ?

Somehow, I managed to hide the menu in the main Thunderbird window, but I don't rememebr how.

## UPDATE

Right-clicking on menu bar does no show option to remove menu bar. See screnshot:

[image]

Comment: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/hidemenubar/ & https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/compact-menu-2/

Comment: @Gantendo - aargh. yet another addon. Could this be done in `about:config` or `userChrome.css` ?

Comment: Very likely, the addons are just zip files you can unpack I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Easy on Windows*!

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to make a new missive.
- Right-click the *Menu Bar.
- Remove check mark from *Menu Bar*.
- Close the dialog.

This setting persists after restarting Thunderbird.

[image: Remove Menu Bar]

However, *Linux users would need a work-around* because the optio to hide the *Menu Bar*(why, Mozilla Team?) is not shown.

[image: No choice to hide menu]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to make a new missive.
- Right-click the Menu Bar.
- Click *Customize*.
- Drag all desired items from the *Composition Toolbar* to the *Menu Bar*.
- Close the dialog.
- Right-click the *Menu Bar*.
- Remove check mark from the *Composition Toolbar*.

*Voilà!*

One toolbar has been removed... but the other is now a bit crowded.

<sup>*sigh*</sup>

[image: Overcrowded Menu Bar]

Comment: but I don't have that option to remove menu bar. See my update with new screenshot.

Comment: @400theCat, Odd... the screenshot above was in T'bird 102.14.0 on Windows. What version and OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Thunderbird 102.14 on Debian 12

Comment: @400theCat, yep, it's missing in Ubuntu T'bird, too. *However*, there is an ersatz "workaround" I've added to the answer. It's annoying that Mozilla has not implemented all features for Linux -- when Win10 expires, I'll be on Ubuntu full time.

Comment: hm, this is not really what I wanted to achieve. Can't the menu be removed without changing the Composition Toolbar? Perhaps by editing UserChrome.css ?