# How to edit shortcut

Tags: windows, start-menu

I would like to know how I can edit a shortcut from Start menu/Taskbar to remove the Thunderbird submenu:

> Compose new message

> Open address book

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1804542/thunderbird-hide-menu-file-edit-view-in-compose-window

Comment: @Gantendo: you didn't understand my question.

Comment: Then you should explain it better.

Comment: I'm talking about just the shortcut in Windows start menu, not the TB features.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to include a screenshot (you can upload it to imgur.com for example). I edited the tags of the question for you

Comment: It's just a simple fork or submenu:

Thunderbird > Compose new message
                     > Open address book